# mkdir permission denied on bluehost server

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, vps, bluehost

I have the following script to upload files. I've been able to run it successfully except for a newly-provisioned VPS from BlueHost. Here is the code:

```
// Creating image upload path
$destinationPath = public_path() . sprintf("/uploads/data/users/%d/", Auth::user()->getId());
$realPath = sprintf("uploads/data/users/%d/", Auth::user()->getId());

if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
    mkdir($destinationPath, 0777, true);
}

$fileName = str_random(16);
$fileName = str_replace('/', 'y', $fileName);
$image_url = $realPath . '/' . $fileName . '.' . $ext;

if ($file->move($destinationPath, $fileName . '.' . $ext)) {
    $p->display_pic = $image_url;
}
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
mkdir(): Permission denied
```

Folder permissions are set to 755 for the parent folder. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with BlueHost, but have you checked that your server (Apache or Nginx, I presume) is the owner of that directory? If not, 755 would prevent the server from writing anything to that dir.

Comment: my guess is that `/uploads/data/users/` one of the folders in this chain does not yet exist, in addition you don't need to set to `0777` the script should be executed under `suexec`

Comment: Please i know next to nothing about linux, please give me some demos.

Comment: @Joel Hinz i have checked like you asked and my server is indeed the owner of the directory.

Comment: @cmorrisey the folder "users" does not exist, that is the whole point of the mkdir(), the condition should check if it exists if not it should create the folder on the server with the specified permissions, or does it not work that way?

Comment: You're close, but it doesn't work recursively. That is, you're trying to create a child directory to the users directory, but if the users directory doesn't exist it won't be created in the process. If you create the users directory first, your script can auto-create as many subdirectories as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy a domain you usually point it to a folder on your server.

Following instructions i found online on how to safely point my laravel project to my domain name without first having to go through the public folder eg:

yahoo.com/home instead of yahoo.com/public_html/home

i moved and renamed the folder my domain was initially pointing to, you will notice that i my code i have:

```
$destinationPath = public_path() . sprintf("/uploads/data/users/%d/", Auth::user()->getId());
```

Now what that would usually mean is that it would check for and create the specified folder if non-existent in the root of the folder my domain was pointing to.

Now since my domain was no more pointed to that folder i assume it tried to create that folder in the "home" directory of my server hence "permission denied"

After taking out the preceeding forward slash it works now. :)
In case you're wondering about the "public_path()" function i have there i tried echoing it out to the page and it came up empty for that i do not know why maybe someone else can explain.